# PHP array key exists

Tags: php, arrays, return

I have 2 arrrays, And i need return TRUE or FALSE when 2 arrays matched each other. also un-ordered arrays should return TRUE if results matched, but only should return true if both arrays have same values.

```
//This should return TRUE
$array_One = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
$array_Two = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
```

---

```
//This should return TRUE
$array_One = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
$array_Two = array('test1', 'test3', 'test2');
```

---

```
//This should return TRUE
$array_One = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
$array_Two = array('test1', 'test3', 'test2');
```

---

```
//This should return FALSE
$array_One = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
$array_Two = array('test1', 'test2');
```

I tried few methods, including array_key_exists by using foreach, But it does not returned the expected result. This should return ONLY one TRUE or FALSE when arrays matched.

Comment: Have you tried [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: The second codeblock, the array values, doesn't match, but you say it should be returning true, is what you want just comparing the sizes of the arrays?

Comment: Agreed with JamWaffles. Do an array_diff and see if the resulting array is empty or not.

Comment: @JamWaffles - you should put that in as an answer.

Comment: @JamWaffles : array_diff return the difference of arrays, So how can I return just only a one TRUE or false ?

Comment: Yes @Kao , you got the right idea. Still I'm thinking how to do that.

Comment: are you comparing size of arrays or matching key/value pairs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

If you just need to know if two arrays' values are exactly the same (regardless of keys and order), then instead of using array_diff, this is a simple method:

```
<?php

function identical_values( $arrayA , $arrayB ) {

    sort( $arrayA );
    sort( $arrayB );

    return $arrayA == $arrayB;
}

// Examples:

$array1 = array( "red" , "green" , "blue" );
$array2 = array( "green" , "red" , "blue" );
$array3 = array( "red" , "green" , "blue" , "yellow" );
$array4 = array( "red" , "yellow" , "blue" );
$array5 = array( "x" => "red" , "y" =>  "green" , "z" => "blue" );

identical_values( $array1 , $array2 );  // true
identical_values( $array1 , $array3 );  // false
identical_values( $array1 , $array4 );  // false
identical_values( $array1 , $array5 );  // true

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the sizes of the arrays, what you can do is use [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

```
if ( count ( $array1 ) == count ( $array2 )) 
{ 
     MATCH! 
} 
else 
{ 
     NO MATCH! 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array_One = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
$array_Two = array('test1', 'test3', 'test2');

if (array_diff($array_One, $array_Two))
{
    // there is a difference
    echo 'FALSE';
}
else
{
    // the arrays match
    echo 'TRUE';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function arraycomp( $array1, $array2 ) {
   $diff1 = array_values( $array1 );
   $diff2 = array_values( $array2 );

   sort( $diff1 );
   sort( $diff2 );

   return ( $diff1 === $diff2 );

}
```

Simply pass in your two arrays to that function.

Comment: Bear in mind, that this ignores the key's as you stated in your question that you were checking the values

Answer (score -1):

this should work for you:

```
sort($array1);
reset($array1);
sort($array2);
reset($array2);
$res = array_diff($array1, $array2);

if($res)
    echo "they match";
```

Comment: why are you using `usort()`?

Comment: And without a second parameter? And missing `$` from the arrays

Comment: Good point. This happenes when you work too much in c )). I hoped to reppresent the idea anyways. Will correct that tho

Comment: so... why are you using `reset()`?

Comment: Because it is always a good idea to reset the arrays after manipulating them